# Least intrusive way to resolve an users city/location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, meteor, geolocation

What I'm trying to do is display a dataset based on the users city. I'm aware that I can use the HTML5 Geolocation method. But is there a less intrusive way that doesn't involve "this webpage wants to know your location"?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, on server side you can get ip and there are services that recognize location by ip. an example:http://www.webservicex.com/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=64

Comment: Noting that location by IP is not particularly reliable or accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My longterm plan is to implement stronger geo detection, so I might as well just do it with HTML5 now.